# In Tomcat application Write Own Log file Using java.util.logging

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

In my Tomcat application using log4j.xml, I am looging my own in log file using

`<param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/applog.log" />`

Now I want do create a separate log file for some business code execution only. I chose to use Java logging -  java.util.logging.

```
FileHandler fh;
FileHandler fileHTML;
try
  { 
  fh = new FileHandler("C:\\Users\\Logging1.txt");
  logger.addHandler(fh);
  SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
  fh.setFormatter(formatter);
  .........
```

But how do I configure this my web application? I think if I can pass a correct path in the `FileHandler` it should work,I tried a lot but I can't get it working.

Comment: Just log, and look in the tomcat server logs.

Comment: Thank for u r reply, Yes my logs from my New java Logger class are available in catlina.<date>.log file, But I need to log in to a separete log file.Please suggest me.